# how to access data of a d3 SVG Element

Tags: dom, svg, element, visualization, d3.js

So I am trying to make my own version of this gorgeous visualization that d3 has done:

http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111116/bundle.html

All I am doing is basically moving the entire chart to the left, and then trying to display the different relationships on right, so every time you hover over a name on the left, not only do you see the different types of connections change colors on the chart, you also see the names of these connections on the right.

The problem I am having is accessing the actual names of the connections. I am new to javascript and even newer to d3, and am having problems understanding how to access the actual names of these SVG elements Thus far I am doing it just in the console.log() by using two lines of code:

```
var targetTest = d3.selectAll("path.link.target-" + d.key);
console.log(targetTest);
```

In the console this will give me a log of all the SVG objects I want, but it gives me the full information for every one of the elements. Something like this:

```
0: SVGPathElement
__data__: Object
animatedNormalizedPathSegList: null
animatedPathSegList: SVGPathSegList
attributes: NamedNodeMap
baseURI: "http://localhost/mbostock-d3-    544addb/examples/bundle2/bundle.html"
childElementCount: 0
childNodes: NodeList[0]
className: SVGAnimatedString
clientHeight: 0
clientLeft: 0
clientTop: 0
clientWidth: 0
dataset: DOMStringMap
externalResourcesRequired: SVGAnimatedBoolean
farthestViewportElement: SVGSVGElement
firstChild: null
firstElementChild: null
id: ""
lastChild: null
lastElementChild: null
localName: "path"
namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
nearestViewportElement: SVGSVGElement
nextElementSibling: SVGPathElement
nextSibling: SVGPathElement  
nodeName: "path"
nodeType: 1
nodeValue: null
normalizedPathSegList: null
offsetHeight: 0
__proto__: SVGPathElement
length: 1
parentNode: HTMLDocument
__proto__: Array[0]
```

The part of the data I am trying to access is within the **data** object, which contains three more objects.

```
source: Object
target: Object
__proto__: Object
```

within the source object, (which is what I am trying to access) there is a field named key, and this is the field I want to access

```
depth: 4
imports: Array[9]
key: "Interpolator"
name: "flare.animate.interpolate.Interpolator"
parent: Object
size: 8746
x: 40.62256809338521
y: 180
```

Basically I want to call a document.write, or similar $(#id).text() on this key, but I only seem to be able to access one element at a time, AKA I am using

```
var target = d3.selectAll("path.link.target-" + d.key);
var source = d3.selectAll("path.link.source-" + d.key);
var imports = source.property("__data__").target.key;
var exports = target.property("__data__").source.key;
```

but each of these will only give me one name, rather then a full list.
AKA when I hover over an element, even if it has multiple "imports" or "exports" the

```
console.log(imports)
```

will only give me 1 name at a time, even though I used selectAll.

Any help would be much appreciated! I'm sorry if the question is a bit convoluted, I tried to be as specific as possible, since it is a very specific question, but I may have gone into to much detail... if that is possible. Anyway thanks before hand!

Isaac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `each` on the `source` and `target` variables to get every value that they return instead of just the first value.

```
var targets = d3.selectAll("path.link.target-" + d.key);
var sources = d3.selectAll("path.link.source-" + d.key);
var imports = [];
var exports = [];
targets.each(function(d) {
  imports.push(d["source"].key);
});
sources.each(function(d) {
  exports.push(d["target"].key);
});
console.log("Imports - " + imports);
console.log("Exports - " + exports);
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brantolsen/bJNyb/) showing it in action. I added the above code to the `mouseover` function since that is where the highlighting is done.

`D3` methods like `attr` and `style` use `each` behind the scenes so you don't have to, but since you are using a custom function to access data you will need to use `each`.

Comment: That makes sense, but when I tried doing it, console shows: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'property'

Comment: Try `imports.push(d["target"].key);` instead. If that does not work, try adding a `console.log(d)` to see what fields `d` has.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how  imports.push(d["target"].key);  is different then what is the code already?  Also, d is an object that includes imports, but I need more imports and exports, which is most of what this problem is coming from

Comment: Added a jsfiddle example to show what I mean. This should show a clear of example of to interact with the nodes.

Comment: Thanks, Get it now! sorry for not responding earlier.

Comment: @BrantOlsen The URL to D3 in your JSFiddle nor longer exists; I created a corrected version [http://jsfiddle.net/76h3svsp/](http://jsfiddle.net/76h3svsp/).